# Value Not printed right for second element of array

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    char *a1[10] = {"123","121"};
    int i =0;
    char *a=NULL;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        a=strcat(a1[i],"0000");
        printf("values %s",a);

    }
}
```

Output of this code comes out to be this
$ ./a.exe
values 1230000 values 0000000

but it should be 
$ ./a.exe
values 1230000 values 1210000

Please tell me where i am wrong

Comment: The values "123" and "121" are located in memory together ('1','2','3','\0','1','2','1','\0'). In the first iteration, you have written "0000' from the first '\0', resulting '1','2','3','0','0','0','0','\0'. In the second iteration, you have written "0000" from the position where the second '\0' was, resulting '1','2','3','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','\0' Therefore you have written outside the original memory positions allocated to those strings. You have programmed a classic buffer overflow. Your code should be used as an example to teach how not programme.

Comment: @Jdamian, no, there is not a buffer overflow, is a segmentation fault.

Comment: @djrocktarun, does your program report a segmentation fault error?

Comment: @djrocktarun, your `char *a1[10]` provides an array of 10 char pointers, not 10-char strings. You have no reserved 10-char strings, therefore, you shouldn't extend those strings.

Comment: this line: char *a1[10] = {"123","121"}; should be: char *a1[] = {"123","121"};  // no array size specified  This will result in the array of 2 pointers to literal strings.  However, you cannot write to literal strings (they are in a readonly page)

Comment: this line: a=strcat(a1[i],"0000"); (note 'a' will be set to the same address as a1[i]) will fail because your trying to write to readonly memory.

Comment: if you change the line: char *a1[10] = {"123","121"}; to char a1[] = { "123", "121" }; then the array a1 will contain the strings rather than pointers to the strings.  then your code can copy a string to an appropriately sized buffer and append some value ("0000") to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want an array of array of `char`, but `char *a1[10]` is an array of pointers to `char` (tipically placed in read-only segments / string literals), trying to modify a string literal usually leads to a segmentation fault.

Change

```
char *a1[10] = {"123","121"};    /* Array of string literals (read only) */
```

to

```
char a1[][10] = {"123","121"};  /* Array of array of char (read - write) */
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is **not** really the modification of string litterals. But the line

```
char *a1[10];
```

affects an array of 10 `char *` and not a pointer to an array of `char[10]` what I suppose OP was expecting (as noted in Jdamian comments).

To create an array of `char[10]`, you must write :

```
char a1[][10] = {"123","121"};
```

That way, you create an array of 2 `char[10]` initialized respectively to `"123"` (in fact, `{ '1', '2, '3, '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'}` as it is **really** a `char[10]`) and "121";

That way you can safely `strcat` `"0000"` to `a1[i]` because 3 (initial length) + 4 (added length) + 1 (terminating null) gives 8 <= 10.

But the really safe way would be :

```
a=strncat(a1[i],"0000", sizeof(a1[0]) - strlen(a1[i]) - 1);
```

Comment: i think `sizeof(a1[0] - strlen(a1) -1)` should be `sizeof(a1[0]) - strlen(a1) -1`

Comment: @mch Oups, I didn't typed what I thought :-( Thanks for noting it (and there was even another mistake : a1 -> a1[i])