# char pointer not printing the right value

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "full_regr.h"

int full_regr()
{
    struct commands *s1=NULL;      
    s1 = (struct commands *)malloc(sizeof(struct commands));        
    Char *token1;
    Char *token2;        
    char *char_frequency_cat;   
    char *frequency_array[100];

    for(j=0;j<=24;j++)
    {   
        token1=strtok(s1->frequency[j],".");  
        token2=strtok(NULL,".");            //rhs of frequency
        if(!token2) //If decimal not placed in frequency
        {
            printf("\t\tFrequencySSM......:==== %s\n",s1->frequency[1]);**     /// it will print 1025
            token1 = strcat(s1->frequency[j],"000000");
            printf("\t\tFrequencySSM......:==== %s\n",s1->frequency[1]);     // it will print 00000
            char_frequency_cat= token1;
            printf("\t\tin if char_freq: %s\n",char_frequency_cat);
        }            

    }
}
```

output is : 
    s1->frequency[0]=1012
    s1->frequency[1]=0000   /// value should be 1025

I am trying to read the value of frequency from an `input.txt` file. Format which we have used in frequency is `FREQ 1012,1025;`
This whole code is in for loop so that one by one each frequency can be read out and used for further process so the problem is that for the first frequency i.e. 1012 it is working but as it comes to `strcat(s1->frequency[j])` the second frequency become zero and if I increase i.e. 3rd frequency I get nothing. 
`char *frequency[1000]` defined in the structure

Comment: What is the definition of `struct commands`? And have you thought about where that `strcat()` call is putting the concatenated string?

Comment: struct commands{
  char *frequency[1000]; };

Comment: i used strcat since i want to add six zeroes to make frequency in MHz. and the value of strcat will going to be save in token1. i put printf in between each line to check

Comment: `for(j=0;j<=24;j++)` this will loop 25 times, is that intended?
Maybe you want to loop only 24 times and then you would write `for(j = 0; j < 24; j++)`.
Also in `if(!token2)` you always print `s1->frequency[1]`, is this also intended? Or you want `s1->frequency[j]`?

Comment: @UniCell, yes sir its 25 times. and secondly i put s1->frequency[1] to check the value at index 1. i want the as loop goes on and should get one by one values of s1->frequency[j]. but in this code for j=0 it was reading the value at s1->frequency[0] and at a same time make the other index value either null or zero. just above and below the strcat i put printf and in comment i write the printed value u can see there.

Comment: Post the whole code. More specifically, show where you allocate room for `s1->frequency[i]` and how you fill it with data. As your question stands now, it seems that you never allocate nor initialize this memory. Nobody can answer this question in its current form.

Comment: i can't post the whole code. Sir the allocation of memory and intialization all the things i have done thats why it is running
 for j=0 properly and pass the test. ijust want you to give me some idea about strcat because i surely know that this is creating prob. earlier also
i post on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797825/value-not-printed-right-for-second-element-of-array through my friend account regarding strcat problem but if i apply those suggestion in my code its not working.

Comment: Why do you assign `NULL` *and* the `malloc` result in sequence?

Comment: this line: token2=strtok(NULL,".");  will NOT get the fractional part of the frequency,  Perhaps a study of the strtok() function would clarify why not.

Comment: the malloc'd memory is being used, but never initialized to any useful value.

Comment: this line: char_frequency_cat= token1; only copies the contents of token1, which is a pointer, then the place where that pointer is pointing is printed.  For this code, the char * char_frequency_cat has no purpose.

Comment: this line: printf("\t\tFrequencySSM......:==== %s\n",s1->frequency[1]);**     /// ... will not compile due to the '**' after the ';'

Comment: this line: token1 = strcat(s1->frequency[j],"000000"); will fail because s1->frequency[j] does not have room to add more characters.  Rather use some temp var like: char longFreq[30] = {'\0'}; strcpy( longFreq, s1->frequency[j]); token1 = strcat(longFreq, "000000");

Comment: this line: for(j=0;j<=24;j++)  uses the 'magic' number 24.  This is very poor coding practice.  Either define it in terms of some struct/array/etc or #define it at the beginning of the program, with some meaningful name.

Answer (score 1):

`s1` points to the memory allocated by `malloc`. This is uninitialized.

Parsing the uninitialized memory with `strtok` gives undefined behavior. If you want to read the file "input.txt" you should open and read it.

Comment: i gave you only some part of coding. i have done intialization ,read and open the input.txt file.